Computing matrixth root of a matrix
Matrixth root of a matrix
In the abovementioned video, final answer to the question is $$\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\-3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}}}= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \displaystyle\frac{-3}{2} & \displaystyle\frac12 \end{bmatrix}$$
But using 'expm' package in R, I obtained the following answer, which answer is correct?
A <- matrix(c(1, 0, -3, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c(2, -1, -3, 2), nrow =2, byrow = TRUE)
logA <- logm(A)
root_logA <- (1/B)*logA
K <- expm(root_logA)
K
        [,1]     [,2]

[1,] 1.0000000  0.000000

[2,] 0.8284271  1.414214

$K= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \displaystyle\frac{3771}{4552} & \sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}$

I didn't watch the video, but I suspect you should be using solve(B) %*% logA instead of (1/B)*logA.

@BenGrossmann, > A <- matrix(c(1, 0, -3, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

B <- matrix(c(2, -1, -3, 2), nrow =2, byrow = TRUE)
solve B%%logA
Error: unexpected symbol in "solve B"
logA <- logm(A)
solve B%%logA
Error: unexpected symbol in "solve B"


You need parentheses around B, solve(B) not solve B

@BenGrossmann,                                                                                                                                 > A <- matrix(c(1, 0, -3, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

B <- matrix(c(2, -1, -3, 2), nrow =2, byrow = TRUE)
logA <- logm(A)
root_logA <- 1/(B)logA
K <- expm(root_logA)
K
[,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.000000
[2,] 0.8284271 1.414214
solve (B)%%logA
[,1]      [,2]
[1,] -2.079442 0.6931472
[2,] -4.158883 1.3862944  After, inserting  (B) also, Answer is different.


Your results are different from the results I get using Python, I'm not sure what's going on there. Also, the results I get using Python don't match the expected answer. The expected answer does arise, however, if we use the formula
$$
A^{1/B} = \exp(\log(A)B^{-1})
$$
Note that your order of multiplication, $B^{-1}\log(A)$, is reversed relative to the above.

The following code produces the result that you're after
library(Matrix)
library(expm)

A <- matrix(c(1, 0, -3, 2), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c(2, -1, -3, 2), nrow =2, byrow = TRUE)
logA <- logm(A)
root_logA <- logA %*% solve(B)
K <- expm(root_logA)

K

